# What happens to the votes and the reputation on a question and answer upon deletion by the OP?

Tags: discussion, reputation

- I have posted a question.
- I get an up vote.
- Someone answers my question.
- I upvote the answer.
- I delete the question.

What happens to the votes and the reputation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During a recalc, all reputation/votes should be lost.